# "necessarily has to"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I want to write:

> X necessarily has to contain a lie.

Am I in the wrong?

1. Should I drop the "has to", since "necessarily" already bears that meaning? I.e. should it be like this instead:

   > X necessarily contains a lie.
2. Or the contrary; perhaps the "has to" part is obligatory?
3. Finally, maybe it's just a matter of preference?

In my own language, these kind of semantic repetitions are shunned. So I kind of want to go for the #1. Then, I have a sense of English that tells me to use #2.

If it is #3, then I'm also open for recommendations and personal preferences. Please, do note that it is your personal preference in that case.

Comment: “Has to” is not obligatory.  You’re fine , and maybe more accurate, to drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, "necessarily" and "has to" say the same thing, so you do not need both. Having both is an example of (grammatical) tautology: this does not make it ungrammatical, but some people prefer to avoid it.